# Resubmitting question

Tags: support, closed-questions, editing, reopen

If my question was marked as unclear and I have reworked it what needs to be done to either:

Get it approved

Or

Resubmit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first edit a closed question it will automatically be submitted to the review queues. Sufficiently high-rep users have the opportunity to view the new version and vote to re-open it or leave it closed.

**Editing is the only approved method of fixing a question, and you should not resubmit.**

If you repost it will be marked as a duplicate of the original. Deleting the original and re-posting is also discouraged, and when noticed a moderator will *un-delete the original* so that the new instance can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Good answer but I'd state it more directly as well. I think it behooves us to be _very_ clear that people should _not_ resubmit closed questions, as new users typically won't know this.